# Plot error: object not found

Tags: r

I am learning in R. 3.1.2

I am watching vid on youtube by Christoph Scherber 
called [Statistics with R (1) - Linear regression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xh6Rex3ARjc)

I am attempting to plot some of the packaged data (airquality) that comes with R:

```
data(airquality)
names(airquality)
#[1] "Ozone"   "Solar.R" "Wind"    "Temp"    "Month"   "Day"
```

both work great, 
but when I attempt to plot data:

```
plot(Ozone-Solar.R,data=airquality)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in effects(Ozone - Solar.R, data = airquality) : 
>     object 'Ozone' not found

I am following example from vid.
I have checked and my spelling and case, both are correct.

Comment: That's a "~" not a "-". Try `plot(Ozone~Solar.R,data=airquality)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names are correct. But you still have an error in your plotting formula: you are supposed to use `~`, not `-`. That is, the *tilde* operator:

```
plot(Ozone ~ Solar.R, data = airquality)
```

The tilde operator creates a *formula* which is passed to the `plot` function. Using the minus operator here doesn’t work, since that attempts to directly evaluate the subtraction. It needs the objects `Ozone` and `Solar.R` for that, and cannot find them.

When using the tilde, by contrast, nothing is evaluated:

```
Ozone ~ Solar.R
# Ozone ~ Solar.R
```

But once passed to `plot`, the function knows to search for the relevant objects inside `airquality`, and to use the data found therein to generate the plot.

Comment: thanks Konrad... the image on the vid was fuzzy... my old eyes.

Answer (score 3):

The correct command is

```
plot(Ozone ~ Solar.R,data=airquality)
```

using a tilde instead of `-`

Comment: thanks so much, on the vid it looks like an -